# Advice requested - passing variables between functions using json/jquery & ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, frontend

I've looked over a lot of 'similar' q&a threads on SO but to be honest, as I don't have too much of a grip on js programming, I'm finding it difficult to make sense of a lot of the answers (as far as they may apply to my own situation).

The context is this, I have two php scripts one returning a list of customer_ids (json encoded) for a set period and the other returning their preferences for news feeds (json encoded).

I wrote the following, having googled a bit to get a basic understanding of how to setup an ajax function in jQuery:

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type:'GET', url: 'cust_selection.php', data: '',
        succes:function(cstmrid) {
            var clistlen = cstmrid.length;
            var i=0;
            var cstmr;
            for( ;cstmr=cstmrid[i++]; ) {
            $('#adminPanel>ul>li').append("<a href='' onclick='alert("+cstmr+")' class='lst_admin basic'>"+cstmr+"</a>"); //alert to be replaced with a function call which passes customerid to the function below.
            }
        },
        dataType:'json'
    });

    var cstmrid = "483972258"; //hardcoded for testing purposes
    $.ajax({
        type:'GET', url:'newsfpref.php?', data:'cref='+cstmrid,
        success:function(npfdata) {
            var item;
            var n=0;
            for( ;item=npfdata[n++]; ) {
                var news = npfdata[n].nsource;
                $('#adminMain>table>tbody').append("<tr><td>"+item+"</td></tr>");
            }
         },
         dataType:'json'
    });
});
```

Now from the first ajax function, I get a list of links which I want to be able to click to launch the second ajax function and pass it the customer id so that it can grab a list of the news sources that they've configured for their pages.
The alert and the hard-coded customer id both suggest that the functions are 'working', but when I try and adjust the first function so that:
...

```
$('#adminPanel>ul>li').append("<a href='' onclick='getCustomerNP("+cstmr+")' class='lst_admin basic'>"+cstmr+"</a>");
```

... is calling a modified version of the second function, as below:
...

```
function getCustomerNP(cstmrid) {
    $.ajax({
        type:'GET', url:'newsfpref.php?', data:'cref='+cstmrid,
        success:function(nprfdata) {
            var item;
            var n=0;
            for( ;item=npfdata[n++]; ) {
                var news = npfdata[n].nsource;
                $('#adminMain>table>tbody').append("<tr><td>"+item+"</td></tr>");
            }
         },
         dataType:'json'
    });
}
```

Everything seems to just fail at this point. The second function doesn't seem to 'receive' the variable and I'm not sure if it's something elementary that I've overlooked (like some muddled up " and ' placements) or if what I am trying to accomplish is actually not the way jQuery ajax functions interact with each other.

As you can see, I've cannibalised bits of code and ideas from many SO q&a threads, but copying without much of an understanding makes for a frustratingly dependent life.

I would appreciate as much - expansive - comment as you can provide, as well as a solution or two (naturally).

EDIT: Not to confuse anyone further, I've been modifying the above and correcting my (many) errors and typos along the way. At present, the code looks like below:

```
$('document').ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET', url: 'cust_selection.php', data: '',
        succes: function (cstmrid) {
            var clistlen = cstmrid.length;
            var i = 0;
            var cstmr;
            for (; cstmr = cstmrid[i++]; ) {
                var a = $("<a href='' class='lst_admin basic'>" + cstmr + "</a>").click(function () {
                    getCustomerNP(cstmr)
                })
                $('#adminPanel>ul>li').append(a); //alert to be replaced with a function call which passes customerid to the function below.
            }
        },
        dataType: 'json'
    });
    function getCustomerNP(cstmr) {
        alert(cstmr);
    }
});
```

Comment: _"like some muddled up " and ' placements"_ - That's what you have done: just after `data:` you've got a `"` instead of a `'`. (Which is why SO's colour syntax highlighting has most of that function in red; that bit is all one big string.)

Comment: that, unfortunately was a typo of mine.

Comment: What happens if you put `alert(cstmrid);` as the first line (or, temporarily, the only line) of the `getCustomerNP()` function?

Comment: I just gave that a go with getCustomerNP(cstmrid) { alert(cstmrid); }

Nothing happened, no alert fired off...

Comment: If the function is declared within your document ready then the inline `onclick=` attributes that you are creating won't find it since they can only call global functions. (As per Charlie's answer.)

Comment: thanks, I've just moved the function outside of the .ready and now the alert is firing cleanly within the function.

Comment: OK. If you want to stick with that style of function declaration and inline `onclick=` then you just need to correct the errors in the `$.ajax()` success callback (I've mentioned several things wrong with it in my answer).

Answer (score 0):

You've got a typo in the `$.ajax()` success function within `getCustomerNP()`. The function declaration:

```
success:function(nprfdata) {
```

... has a parameter `nprfdata`, but then within the function you use `npfdata` (missing the `r`).

Also this code:

```
        var item;
        var n=0;
        for( ;item=npfdata[n++]; ) {
            var news = npfdata[n].nsource;
            $('#adminMain>table>tbody').append("<tr><td>"+item+"</td></tr>");
        }
```

...declares and sets variable `news` that you never use. And it doesn't seem right to increment `n` in the `for` test expression but then use `n` within the loop. You never set `item` to anything but you use it in your `.append()`.

(Note also that JS doesn't have block scope, only function scope, so declaring variables inside an if or for loop doesn't limit them to that if or for block.)

I would not create inline `onclick` handlers like that. I'd probably do something more like this:

```
$('#adminPanel>ul>li').append("<a href='' data-cstmr='"+cstmr+"' class='lst_admin basic'>"+cstmr+"</a>");
```

...and then within the document ready setup a delegated event handler to catch the clicks on those anchors:

```
$('#adminPanel>ul>li').on('click', 'a.lst_admin', function() {
    $.ajax({
        type:'GET', url:'newsfpref.php?', data:'cref='+ $(this).attr('data-cstmr'),
        success:function(npfdata) {
            var item,
                n=0,
                // cache the jQuery object rather than reselecting on every iteration
                $table = $('#adminMain>table>tbody'); 
            // increment n only after the current iteration of the loop               
            for( ;item=npfdata[n]; n++) {
                // change to use item
                $table.append("<tr><td>"+item.nsource+"</td></tr>");
            }
         },
         dataType:'json'
    });
});
```

Comment: Yikes... I really am sloppy. I've been editing and re-editing this script for the last hour, so I've unfortunately introduced more errors than I started out with (or atleast, than I had an hour and a half ago).

Comment: nnnnnn,thanks for the detailed response. I've corrected the typo in my script, I'll correct the ones in the posting in a moment. Is there a particular reason to avoid the inline onclick?

Comment: You're welcome. I just edited a couple more corrections into my answer, but I might've missed some other similar issues. Regarding the inline `onclick` code, it can only access global functions which is kind of messy.

Comment: I'm going to try this out tomorrow morning (it's 5:20am here). I will make more mistakes if I try and do this tonight. Again thank you and Charlie for all the help.

Comment: I think I've found the problem. For some reason, there are spaces injected in the return from the first function. So instead of building the following query:
    newsfpref.php?cstmrid=483972258

It creates:
    newsfpref.php?cstmrid = 483972258

I think I need to just use a javascript trim/replace function before passing 'cstmrid='+cval into the second function.

Comment: No matter what I try, that second ajax function is just not executing the newsfpref.php?cstmrid=x command.

Comment: wow! finally found the answer for this. The second function's default return is what caused all the problems. By adding "return false;" to the function, the code worked fine.

I looked into this return false and found that it actually does 3 separate tasks [http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/] of which I only wanted preventDefault();
So, the second function looks like this now:
    $(selector).on('click' ... function(ev) { ...
        $.ajax({ ... });
        ev.preventDefault();
    });

Answer (score 0):

As you append your like with `<a href='' onclick='getCustomerNP("+cstmr+")'`, Make sure you can access the function `getCustomerNP`.
Try to define `getCustomerNP` as

```
window.getCustomerNP = function(cstmrid) {
    ...
```

If you defined it in the `$(document).ready(function(){ ... })` block, try this

```
    $('document').ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET', url: 'cust_selection.php', data: '',
            succes: function (cstmrid) {
                var clistlen = cstmrid.length;
                var i = 0;
                var cstmr;
                for (; cstmr = cstmrid[i++]; ) {
                    var a = $("<a href='' class='lst_admin basic'>" + cstmr + "</a>").click(function () {
                        getCustomerNP(cstmr)
                    })
                    $('#adminPanel>ul>li').append(a); //alert to be replaced with a function call which passes customerid to the function below.
                }
            },
            dataType: 'json'
        });

        function getCustomerNP(cstmrid) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET', url: 'newsfpref.php?', data: 'cref=' + cstmrid,
                success: function (nprfdata) {
                    var item;
                    var n = 0;
                    for (; item = npfdata[n++]; ) {
                        var news = npfdata[n].nsource;
                        $('#adminMain>table>tbody').append("<tr><td>" + item + "</td></tr>");
                    }
                },
                dataType: 'json'
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Charlie, I just tried that out and yes, I can access the function, the alert(cstmrid); inside the widow.getCustomerNP fires off cleanly now.

Comment: Is there a reason why window... might work, as opposed to the way I was defining the function before?

Comment: If you defined the `getCustomerNP` in the `$('document').ready(function() {....}` the `onclick` will can not access it.

Comment: oh, ok that's something I didn't know at all (I'm a complete novice - if you can't tell). Is it because the function won't be 'created' until after ajax has set-up the links and failed to call it already?

Comment: Hi Charlie, I tried the above code example, keeping the getCustomerNP() function within the $('document').ready(function() {...}.
Before putting the ajax function in, I tried a simple alert(), to see if the data was getting there, but I received an alert pop-up with "undefined" in it.
The list works and produces a list of customer ids, so that part isn't broken and, by all logic that I know, getCustomerNP(cstmr) should be sending the customer id to the getCustomerNP() function.

Maybe I should scrap my initial approach and code it more according to your best practice advice?

Comment: Hi, never used it before, just looked at the site, seems to want html, css as well. Do you want me to put the code I wrote up there in jsFiddle or the whole set of html/css and javascript?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/codephobic/QP4zC/
I've got the alert() working now, I think I might be on the right tracks again.
I got rid of the onclick and used nnnnnn's suggested event handler within the .ready(...).
Now I need to put the rest of the function in, so that it creates the table rows.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/codephobic/V9QP4/1/ - currently where I'm at. I've got the alert() firing correctly (I think), as it shows the customer id of the link that I click. Yet, when I try and put in the ajax function, it doesn't work.

Comment: Hi, I find that `fData` which is undefined.

Comment: Hi Charlie, I've just corrected that in both the script and the jsfiddle. In that function, is it not the case that the variable is implicitly given the value of whatever is in data:'cstmrid='+cval?